# I've been trying to solve this but i just can't find any solved exemples on the internet, can someone help me with these?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^4 x_{ij} = 15
$$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^4
k_{ij} = i+1,\qquad i=1,2,3$$
$$
\sum_{i=0}^4 x_{ij}=5, \qquad j=1,2,\ldots,4
$$
I've been trying to solve this but I just can't find any solved examples on the internet, can someone help me with these?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Try to draw the matrix and understand what the different results look like. Is it possible to solve for all of the entries in the matrix? There should be $3\times 4 = 12$ entries ... So start by drawing a 3 by 4 grid on paper or something.

Comment: What are $k_{ij}$'s?

Comment: Your first has $12$ numbers that sum to $15$.  Without knowing something about the $x_{ij}$ there is not nearly enough information to solve it.  The others also have more variables than equations so cannot be solved.  Even if they are to be solved together and the $k_{ij}$ are supposed to be $x_{ij}$ you have only $8$ equations in $12$ unknowns.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^3 x_{ij} = 5$ in your last equation?  If so, the first equation is inconsistent with these.